# I can't pass a variable from my jQuery code to my PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to pass a variable from my jQuery code to my HTML/PHP code using AJAX and POST, but I get the error message "Notice: Undefined index: testData in C:\xampp\htdocs\teszt\test1.php on line 9".

I'm using XAMPP, I'm running the code in localhost, I'm using Mozilla Firefox and here's my HTML/PHP code (test1.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php echo "<p class='testParagraph'>" . $_POST['testData'] . "</p>";?>

        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's my jQuery code (script1.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var temporaryVariable = "temporary variable";

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test1.php",
        data: { testData:"2" },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        }
      }).done(function() {
        $('.testParagraph').addClass( temporaryVariable );
        });
});
```

What I tried changing so far (but didn't work of course):

test1.php:

1. charset was previously `iso-8859-2`
2. `GET` instead of `POST` in both codes
3. commenting out the `script` tag includes

script1.js:

1. commenting out the `$(document).ready(function() {...` lines
2. in `data:` I tried changing the quote symbols from `'` to `"` or no quote symbols at all
3. commenting out the `success: function...` line and the two lines below it

Also, when I run the PHP code, the `p` tag gets the `temporaryVariable` class from the jQuery code.

Still, I get the error message written above. I would appreciate any help I get.

Comment: One thing you should do is first do `if(isset($_POST['testData']))` because it sounds like there is no `$_POST['testData']`. `print_r($_POST)` to see what is set there.

Comment: do you want to put result returned by ajax in `p` ??

Comment: can you show the php code

Comment: Are you posting `test1.php` to `itself` -- that how it sounds  -- why would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your test1.php to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <p id='testParagraph'>&nbsp;</p> <!-- You receive the value by jquery not from PHP. -->

        <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And your script1.js to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var temporaryVariable = "temporary variable";

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test1.php",
        data: { testData:"2" },
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        }
      }).done(function() {
        $('#testParagraph').html(temporaryVariable); //The value is inserted into the paragraph.
        });
});
```

Hope works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are getting the php page from a post request, using `$_POST['testData']` will be of no use and will always give an index not found error. If you want to set the value in the `p` tag from jquery, you could use `$('.testParagraph').html( temporaryVariable )` instead of `.addClass`

Answer (score 0):

Use data : 'testData=2',

Instead of data : {testData:"2"},

Answer (score 0):

> Notice: Undefined index: testData in C:\xampp\htdocs\teszt\test1.php
>   on line 9

means your

> ```
>     data: { testData:"2" },
> ```

is wrong.

Didn't test it, but this should work:

> ```
>     data: [ testData:"2" ],
> ```

because $_POST is an Array

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're posting `test1.php` to itself, and it's not clear why you would do that.

As @Rasclatt has pointed out in the comments check to see if the data exists before you try to access it.

Change:

```
<?php echo "<p class='testParagraph'>" . $_POST['testData'] . "</p>";?>
```

To:

```
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['testData'] ) ) {
    echo "<p class='testParagraph'>" . $_POST['testData'] . "</p>";
} 
?>
```

If, however, `test1.php` is a different script altogether then make the following changes:

Include a placeholder for the ajax content in your HTML:

```
<p class="tetParagraph"></p>
```

Trim and edit your JavaScript to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var tempVal = "temporary variable";
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test1.php",
        data: { testData:"2" },
        success: function (result) {
            tempVal = result;
            $('.testParagraph').html( tempVal );
            alert('success');
        }
   });
});
```